# Using Generic Input in a Functional Interface

Tags: java, function, generics, netbeans

I have an object that's designed to paginate a list and send a page of the results to a user.  However, I want to be able to use Functions to pass behavior to this object.  The behavior will be used by the object to dynamically generate the content of the lines using methods inside the objects in the list.

```
public class InteractiveJSONList<T> {

    private final List<T> list;

    private List<Function<T, Object>> formatArgFunctionSequence;

    // ... Irrelevant code truncated.

    // Constructor
    public InteractiveJSONList(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

I'm using generics to define the type of list, and likewise, the input type of the function.  However, when attempting to define the Function as input to a method, NetBeans doesn't seem to recognize the input object as the correct type (it simply treats it as an instance of Object).

This code snippet resides inside an instance method in InteractiveJSONList.  The method is designed to extract information from each item in the list and use the results as format arguments for String.format later on.

```
    for (T item : itemsList) {
        index++;

        // Create a new JSON Message.
        new JSONMessage(resultLinesBaseMessage)
                .setFormatArguments(index, stringFunctionSequence.stream()
                        .map(o -> o.apply(item))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                        .toArray(new Object[stringFunctionSequence.size()]))
    }
```

I'm using Java 8's Stream methods to apply the function using each item in the list as input, then collecting the results and submitting them as an array for a varArgs method to use later in String.format.

Finally, this is an attempt to implement the mechanism.

```
List<String> data = ... //Using Strings at this point, but could be anything.

new InteractiveJSONList<String>(data)
        .setStringBuildingSequence(input -> input.substring(0,5));
```

I'm only using `String` and its method `substring` as an example for how I want this mechanism to work.  Certain objects in this list will be more complicated than Strings, and will have getters for variables inside the object.  I want to define the behavior required to get variables from within the items in this list, and then use them to generate dynamic results.  However, NetBeans won't recognize `input` as a member of String, and I subsequently am not able to use String's methods.  `input` is only recognized as an object, even though InteractiveJSONList's generic type `T` is defined as a `String` when the object was created.

Am I setting up generics incorrectly?  I might be led to think it's as simple as that, however, I tested this instead:

```
List<String> data = ... //Using Strings at this point, but could be anything.

Function<String, Object> testFunction = input -> new InteractiveText(input.substring(0, 8));

new InteractiveJSONList<String>(data)
        .setStringBuildingSequence(testFunction);
```

And it compiled and ran correctly.

Any advice?  Also, if this is a terrible practice for my desired purpose, please let me know.  Thank you!

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem, can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: And btw, you can change: `.collect(Collectors.toList())
                        .toArray(new Object[stringFunctionSequence.size()]))` to just `toArray()`.

Comment: I'm supplying the array size in the `toArray()` method so that the array is initialized with the exact size required, since I know it already. (Otherwise it will be initialized with the default size of 10, to my knowledge.)  But I appreciate the feedback!

Comment: Jorn I'll try to get a reproducible example created.

Comment: If the stream has the `SIZED` characteristic, which it will with a `List`, the created array should have exactly the right size to fit all elements

Comment: Oh, thank you much!  That is helpful to know.

Comment: The definition of `setStringBuildingSequence`, the very method you have trouble with, is missing. Besides, there is no “default size of 10” in `Stream.toArray()`, even for streams with an unknown size.